# EF5 .Local performance

Tags: performance, entity-framework

I'm doing this on a table with ~43k rows:

```
MyDbContext.Stores.Load();
MyDbContext.Stores.Local.Count.Dump(); //horrible performance!
```

I can see through the profiler that the first instruction fires up the select statement to fetch all rows. Actually the second instruction returns the correct value but after ~12 seconds, and it is not what I was expecting considering that all data should be in memory.
What is wrong (or what is its real purpose) with .Local in Entity Framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should do this:

```
var stores = MyDbContext.Stores.ToList();

// stores is in memory after executing .ToList()
var count = stores.Count();
```

[DbSet.Local Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696248%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)

> This property returns an ObservableCollection that contains all
>   Unchanged, Modified, and Added objects that are currently tracked by
>   the context for the given DbSet. The returned observable collection
>   stays in sync with the underlying DbSet collection and the contents of
>   the context. This means that you can modify the observable collection
>   or add/remove entities to/from the underlying DbSet collection (that
>   includes adding entities by executing a query) and both collections
>   will be synchronized.
>
> This property is often used in data binding applications.